# UITableViewController tableView size in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout

I need to design a menu screen in Storyboard, but the issue is the menu screen is never the fill size of UIWindow on iPhone/iPad. It is typically 1/4th the width of the screen and full height of UIWindow. How do I resize UITableViewController in Storyboard so as to be able to design the cell visually? Also how do I set the auto constraints of this tableView to occupy only 1/4th the size of parent view/window?

Comment: You cannot set constraints of one view controller's view in relation to another view controller's view unless they are superview and subview of each other. If you want us to make suggestions that might help with what you're doing, please _show_ us what you're doing. Don't talk about your code; show your actual code. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of designing your self you can use any third party Library to do so. For ex https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu/blob/master/README.md there many other. If you want to design your own there are tutorials you can follow.

Comment: want to design a side drawer menu ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a normal UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController and put a UITableView in it. That way you can resize it however you want with constraints.